# Skobbler maps UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, skmaps

I started working with skobbler maps, followed the guide on skobbler website to add its dependencies to project, however upon building the app it gives this error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ski.com.skobblerapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libngnative.so"
```

The libngnative.so is present in jniLibs directory inside app, still i am getting this error, how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

The structure of the jniLibs folder must be as described at http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec001

Have you looked at the provided [demo](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download) project?